# Why main() function gets executed again and again only when interrupt- ISR(ADC_vect) gets executed?

Tags: arduino, interrupt, avr, arduino-uno, avr-gcc

I am making a digital clock based project, using an `atmega328p` on a breadboard.  I connected 4 buttons to the `ADC3` channel, and I'm using `INT0` as a trigger to start ADC conversion. I also enabled the `TimerCounter1` to calculate the time.

I am having trouble with increasing the time using the increase button, because the `setTime(3, 30)` function call is in the `int main()` function and after pressing the button this function `setTime(3, 30)` is getting executed again and again. This happens only when `ISR(ADC_vect)` gets executed.

This is the part of my code I think is relevant:

**xxx.ino**

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // PB5
  DDRB |= (1<<DDB5);

  // ### Want to see how many times these functions - __init__timer(), setTime(), __init__button() gets executed after the Interrupt ###
  PORTB ^= (1<<PORTB5);

  __init__timer();
  
  //setTime(3, 30);

  __init__button();

  while(1)
  { 

  }

  return 0;
}

void __init__timer()
{ 
  // Enable the global Interrupt
  SREG |= (1<<7);
  // Enable the output compare match on comapare A 
  TIMSK1 |= (1<<OCIE1A);

  // Set TimerCounter1 in CTC mode
  TCCR1A &= ~(1<<WGM10);
  TCCR1A &= ~(1<<WGM11);
  TCCR1B |= (1<<WGM12);
  TCCR1B &= ~(1<<WGM13);

  // Set the prescalr to 1024 so we get 15625 Hz pulses(counts) per second
  TCCR1B |= (1<<CS10);
  TCCR1B &= ~(1<<CS11);
  TCCR1B |= (1<<CS12);

  // Assign the OCR1A to 46875 (3 seconds)
  OCR1A = 46875;
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{ 
  Serial.println("ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled");
}

void __init__button()
{
  // Select the voltage referance - AREF pin
  ADMUX &= ~(1<<REFS1);
  ADMUX &= ~(1<<REFS0);

  // Select the input channel - ADC3
  ADMUX |= (1<<MUX0);
  ADMUX |= (1<<MUX1);
  ADMUX &= ~(1<<MUX2);
  ADMUX &= ~(1<<MUX3);

  // Configure the ADCSRA registor

  SREG |= (1<<7);
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADIE);

  // Set the prescalar to 128 - 125KHz
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADPS0);
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADPS1);
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADPS2);

  // Enable the INT0 
  EIMSK |= (1<<INT0);
  EICRA |= (1<<ISC00);
  EICRA |= (1<<ISC01);

  ADCSRB &= ~(1<<ADTS0);
  ADCSRB |= (1<<ADTS1);
  ADCSRB &= ~(1<<ADTS2);
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADATE);

  // This will start the conversion if trigger INT0 is pressed
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADEN);
}

ISR(ADC_vect)
{
  if((ADC < 750) && (ADC > 600))
  {
    Serial.println("Button 1 -> PB5 toggled");
  }
  if((ADC < 500) && (ADC > 350))
  {
    Serial.println("Increase time button pressed... -> PB5 toggled");
    // increaseTime();
  }
  if((ADC < 300) && (ADC > 200))
  {
    Serial.println("Decrease button pressed... -> PB5 toggled");
    // decreaseTime();
  }
  if((ADC < 200) && (ADC > 100))
  {
    Serial.println("button 4 -> PB5 toggled");
  }
}
```

And this is the Serial output:

```
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
Increase time button pressed... -> PB5 toggled
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
Increase time button pressed... -> PB5 toggled
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
Increase time button pressed... -> PB5 toggled
I⸮Increase time button pressed... -> PB5 toggled
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
Increase time button pressed... -> PB5 toggled
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) executed. -> PB5 Not toggled
```

#### My question:

Why are the instructions in the `int main()` function executed again and again when `ISR(ADC_vect)` gets executed, but not when `ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)` gets executed? The `PB5` pin toggles only when `ISR(ADC_vect)` gets executed.

Comment: I don't know for sure but you are using Arduino framework, and you are basically replaced the Arduino [main()](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp#L33-L51) running behind the scene with your own main(), and some of the things might not get setup or initialised correctly...

Comment: I actually made this project using avr-gcc and avrdude, not using arduino ide. But I wanted to show the output on the serial monitor so I write only the problematic section os the code in arduino ide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what was wrong - Why `main()` function was executing again only when `ISR(ADC_vect)` interrupt occurs.

Just like the answer above by `djph` said, `main()` function only executes once and then it loops forever in `while(1);` And when an interrupt occurs the program pause the current task and jump from the loop-`while(1);` to the respective interrupt routine -`ISR()` and after that the program jump back to the loop-`while(1)`, means it will not execute the `main()` function again after an `ISR()` interrupt execution.

So, In my case the `main()` function is executing again only if the ISR(ADC_vect) interrupt occurs. Why?

###### The Answer:

If we look at how I initialized the ADC ->

`void __init__button()` function:

```
// Select the voltage referance - AREF pin
  ADMUX &= ~(1<<REFS1);
  ADMUX &= ~(1<<REFS0);

  // Select the input channel - ADC3
  ADMUX |= (1<<MUX0);
  ADMUX |= (1<<MUX1);
  ADMUX &= ~(1<<MUX2);
  ADMUX &= ~(1<<MUX3);

  // Configure the ADCSRA registor

  SREG |= (1<<7);
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADIE);

  // Set the prescalar to 128 - 125KHz
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADPS0);
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADPS1);
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADPS2);

  // Enable the INT0 
  EIMSK |= (1<<INT0);
  EICRA |= (1<<ISC00);
  EICRA |= (1<<ISC01);

  ADCSRB &= ~(1<<ADTS0);
  ADCSRB |= (1<<ADTS1);
  ADCSRB &= ~(1<<ADTS2);

  // 
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADATE);

  // This will start the conversion if trigger INT0 is pressed
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADEN);
```

ADC Auto Trigger Enable Bit, The ADC will start a conversion on a positive edge of the selected trigger signal - which is `INT0`.

```
ADCSRA |= (1<<ADATE);
```

```
  // Enable the INT0 
  EIMSK |= (1<<INT0);
  EICRA |= (1<<ISC00);
  EICRA |= (1<<ISC01);
```

So that means if I press the button not only the `ADC` interrupt will occur but also the `INT0` interrupt will occur too, **But in my code there is no `ISR(INT0_vect)` routine.** This is the problem...
After adding `ISR(INT0_vect)` routine to my code the `main()` function is not executing again when `ISR(ADC_vect)` interrupt occurs,

```
ISR(INT0_vect)
{ 
  // Do nothing
}
```

And finally in my digital clock project, I am now able to increase the Time when I press the increase button... Thank You.

There may be better ways to do this but this works for me.

I don't know why `main()` function executes again if that perticular interrupt occurs of which we forget to add the respective routine - `ISR()` to the code.

###### EDIT :

I think I do know now why `main()` gets executed again -
If an unexpected interrupt occurs (interrupt is enabled and no handler is installed, which usually indicates a bug), then the default action is to reset the device by jumping to the reset vector.

`ISR()` interrupts in detail : [www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html#:%7E:text=An%20interrupt%20routine%20is%20defined,handler%20for%20the%20specified%20peripheral.)

And this is the better way to handle empty interrupts -

```
EMPTY_INTERRUPT(INT0_vect);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in any function runs once, in sequence, from the start of the function to the end.  In the case of your `main()` function there, it gets as far as the infinite loop, and stays there forever.

Interrupts (and the functions attached to their calling vectors) are "special" segments of code that get called out of sequence.  That is, they interrupt the normal program flow when they need to run (such as when a timer compare happens), then return the CPU right back to where it was.

In your case, the instruction flow at the point of the infinite loop ends up being something to the effect of

```
loop:
  nop       ; do absolutely nothing
  rjmp loop   ;go back to the "loop" label
```

In the event of an interrupt, the execution path will look essentially like this:

```
loop:
  rjmp interrupt ;to the interrupt
  (... interrupt here ...)
  return here    ; back from interrupt
  nop       ; do absolutely nothing
  rjmp loop   ;go back to the "loop" label
```